# jQuery UI sortable() method not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a to-do list with jQuery and tried adding jQuery UI to make the list items sortable, but the code I tried didn't work.

Here are the relevant parts of my code that I changed in attempt (view [CodePen](https://codepen.io/nataliecardot/pen/VXmPrO) for full code). What am I doing incorrectly?

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="designs.js"></script>

  <ul>
    <li class="sortable">Work on projects for one hour</li>
    <li class="sortable">Go for a walk</li>
    <li class="sortable">Meditate</li>
    <li class="sortable">Stretch</li>
  </ul>
```

JavaScript

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    let toAdd = $('input[name="listItem"]').val();
    // If nothing in input box, ceases function execution
    if (toAdd === '') return;
    // Inserts li as first child of ul
    $('ul').prepend('<li class="sortable">' + toAdd + '</li>');
    // Clears input box after clicking '+'
    $('input[name="listItem"]').val('');
});

$('.sortable').sortable();
```

Comment: You haven't specified what the specific problem is and what is or isn't working as expected or even what you expect this code to do. Take a few minutes to read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: I expect the list items to be sortable. The specific problem is the code I added to do so doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix these things in your code:

1. Include jQuery UI **after** jQuery.
2. Add `.sortable` class to `<ul>` and remove it from `<li>`